# Unable to make libtool incorporate yasm-created object files

Tags: c, automake, libtool, yasm

I'm trying to get `libtool` and `yasm` to work together.

`yasm` creates the correct `.o files` from my `.asm` sources, but I can't figure out how to get `libtool` to build the associated `.lo` and `.dep` files.
It wants to build the shared library, incorporating the `.o` files.

Answer (score 0):

`libtool` generated files typically use the following layout: The `.lo` file in a `build` directory consisting of location metadata; the static object `.o` files in the `build` directory; and the PIC / shared `.o` objects in the `build/.libs` directory.

You can use the libtool compile mode. I'm not familiar with yasm, so you'll have to fill in the switches. It will run the `yasm` build twice, once with `-DPIC` (and maybe other shared object options).

`libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile yasm <options> src.asm`

If using automake, this may require an explicit rule for the `.asm` files:

```
.asm.lo:
        $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile \
        yasm <options> $<
```

Keep in mind that those are TABs in Makefiles, not (8) space characters!
You might also need to add: `.SUFFIXES: .asm .lo` prior to this. I use the variable `$(LIBTOOL)`, because some platforms (OSX for example) need to install it as `glibtool`, and it's what `Makefile.in`does.

The generated `src.lo`, `src.o`, `.libs/src.o` should be respected by `make clean` for example.

For your library `libfoo`, you will need to let automake know about these sources with: `EXTRA_libfoo_la_SOURCES = src.asm`, and obj deps with `libfoo_la_LIBADD = src.lo`. It might be even be worthwhile adding to dependencies: `libfoo_la_DEPENDENCIES = src.lo`.

Though I don't see why just putting `src.asm` in `libfoo_la_SOURCES` wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: This is pretty much where I ended up too, and there are problems: first, the _.asm.lo_ command is only run once by libtool (I'm using a shell script as a front-end to yasm underneath, that shell script is only executed once in response to the command "make XXX.lo"); second, the _XXX.lo_ file is created in the top-level Makefile directory, not the source directory. I could change my shell script to create both _.libs/XXX.o_ and _XXX.o_ in a single execution, and I could move the _XXX.lo_ file explicitly, but doing that seems fragile (and wrong when not building a shared library).

Comment: Edit: I've figured out where I was going wrong on creating both static and shared objects, my script error. Is there a recipe for where libtool creates the _XXX.lo_ file?

Answer (score 0):

This works (although I never did figure out how to get libtool to create the `.lo` file in the target directory, or to create the target directory's `.libs` directory).

The Makefile rule:

```
# Rule to build object files from asm files.
#
# XXX
# Libtool creates the .lo file in the directory where make is run. Move the file
# into place explicitly; I'm sure this is wrong, but have no idea how to fix it.
# Additionally, in a parallel make, the .libs file may not yet be created, check
# as necessary, but ignore errors.
.asm.lo:
        -d=`dirname $@`; test $d/.libs || mkdir $d/.libs
        $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile sh $(srcdir)/dist/yasm.sh $< $@
        rm -f $@
        mv `basename $@` $@
```

A support shell script to do the yasm call:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Libtool support for yasm files, expect the first argument to be a path to
# the source file and the second argument to be a path to libtool's .lo file.
# Use the second argument plus libtool's -o argument to set the real target
# file name.
source=$1
target=`dirname $2`
while test $# -gt 0
do
        case $1 in
        -o)
                target="$target/$2"
                shift; shift;;
        *)
                shift;;
        esac
done

yasm -f x64 -f elf64 -X gnu -g dwarf2 -D LINUX -o $target $source
```